# FAT16 - Timestamp for last modification of entire FAT table, or way to determine whether cluster chain has changed less than O(n)?

Tags: fat16

Is there a timestamp somewhere for the last time the FAT table has been changed?  I need a way to flatten cluster chains (for constructing NewtonOS VBOs, which uses a single object that then has pointers to other objects/sectors).  Or a particular cluster chain, other than traversing the whole thing in O(N)?